# Finding a point inside a Boost::Geometry::Polygon

Tags: c++, boost, computational-geometry, boost-geometry

I have a `Polygon` object and I'm looking for an efficient way to find any point strictly inside it (not on its boundary). What is the best way to do so?

I had the following ideas, which I don't really like:

1. Triangulating the polygon and reporting a point on one of the triangulation edges (too expensive).
2. Checking the polygon's winding direction and reporting a point located in an epsilon-distance from one of the polygon's edges (doesn't work in edge-cases).

Comment: What's wrong with the standard winding number or crossing number [methods](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html)?

Comment: @Sam, I don't see how the winding/crossing number helps finding a point inside the polygon. Note that my question wasn't about checking whether a given point is inside the polygon, but about finding one that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a polygon, you can find the *first* two points where the polygon **crosses** a line parallel to x axis and lies between the yMin & yMax of your polygon (0 & 1 in the image below).

Any point between these points will be inside your polygon. The basic idea comes from scan converting a polygon —i.e. these are the points you would *fill*. The part of the line after the second point has a winding of 0 or 2, depending on your polygon.

The first two crossings (or last) has to be taken, as the crossing points are sorted along the x-axis.

[image: Basic idea]

Some *corner* cases:

1. If you omit *all* points of the polygon which just touches the line, in some cases this can fail (image below).
2. If there are overlapping lines in your polygon, you have to resolve those.

[image: issue]

To avoid the first issue, make sure to take the first point as a definite crossing and the next one can be either a crossing or a point where polygon just touches the line.

[image: final]

This can be easily implemented without using any special functions in most languages. Since I am not familiar with Boost methods, I am posting a sketch of the basic idea in javascript.

The drawing is done using *paper.js* —although, the code for the algorithm outlined here itself is self contained.

You can translate this to C++ as long as you can enumerate through all points in a Boost::polygon

Here is the [demo](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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).

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling with the implementation of this. I see that `Boost::Intersection` can't handle the corner cases. How do you implement this in Boost?

Comment: I am not familiar with Boost libraries, but this algorithm is fairly straightforward to implement in most languages. I added a demo in javascript which is self contained.